# Redirect To Google AppEngine when my server down

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, vps

Hi All
i know this questions sound stupid.
But i wondering if there is a way to redirect my website to google appengine when the server down.
This is my scenario:
I'm using Google AppEngine to host my static files, and i own a blog which is host on a VPS. But sometimes the VPS down for more than 6 hours without notice. 
So i come with this idea, how about if i host the "down for maintenance page" on appengine, and when my server is down, it will redirect to something like this: maintenance.somedomain.com which is host on appengine. So my visitors know what is going on.
If any of you know how to do this, please help me.
I really appreciate all your time and effort.
Thanks

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some DNS providers are offering this kind of failover services. One example is zoneedit http://www.zoneedit.com/failover.html but there are probably plenty of others ase well.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger issue is a VPS being down for a long time, sounds like you need a new host. Load balancing is what you need to Google for this idea, though.

Comment: The first idea that come in my mind is, add my domain to GAE, and add setup the ns server in godaddy. As i know, if the first 2 ns failed, then it will search for the next ns. where the 3rd or 4th ns would be GAE. Later in GAE, i will setup a code that will ping my vps, if it return 404 or unreachable, then show maintenance page. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through code since the code to do the redirect is part of the unreachable site.  You would need a load balancer, proxy or some other network level redirector that would be able to detect the server state independent of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with DNS: Have your www subdomain CNAMEd to your server normally, and change that (manually or via an automated process running somewhere other than your server) to point to ghs.google.com when you want to send traffic to App Engine. Make sure you have Google Apps configured to serve your domain via your App Engine app.

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, though - why not just host the content on App Engine full time?

Comment: i have a Wordpress blog which is running using PHP. As i know GAE is not natvively support PHP. So i would like to host just a maintenance page to serve when my vps down.